# JSON response appended with extra properties using jQuery File-Upload plugin in Struts 2

Tags: java, json, servlets, struts2, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jQuery File-Upload plugin with Struts 2.

In my action I am populating the JSON object `"results"` and that's all I want my action to return.

But it is also including the plugin's `file` object as well which is an incomplete JSON and causing everything to break on my callbacks.
(Please note that if I don't populate my `result` object then it will return a valid JSON `"file"` object.

Is there any way I could avoid returning the `"file"` JSON response? I just want my action to return only `"results"`

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "ExcelPath": "/usr/test/test.xlsx",
            "ExcelName": "test.xlsx",
            "TestExcelStatus": "success"
        }
    ] 
}
{
    "file": {
        "absolute": true,
        "absoluteFile": null,
        "absolutePath": "\/usr\/local\/apache-tomcat-7.0.39\/temp"
    },
    "path": "\/usr\/local\/apache-tomcat-7.0.39\/temp\/up
```

**My `Action` is as below:**

```
org.json.JSONObject resp = new JSONObject();            
JSONArray resultsArray = new JSONArray();
resp.put("results",resultsArray);
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();           
result.put("TestExcelStatus", "success");
result.put("ExcelName", this.fileFileName);
result.put("ExcelPath", fileToCreate.getPath());
resultsArray.put(result);
    

servletResponse.reset();
servletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
servletResponse.setHeader("CacheControl","no-cache");
servletResponse.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
servletResponse.setHeader("Expires","-1");
//resp.writeJSONString(out);
resp.write(servletResponse.getWriter());
```

I am expecting the below line to clear the existing JSON and only return my `"results"` JSON. But it is still returning every thing.

```
servletResponse.reset();
```

And the desired JSON response must be as below without a `"file"`.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "ExcelPath": "/usr/test/test.xlsx",
            "ExcelName": "test.xlsx",
            "TestExcelStatus": "success"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this this will help in any way. Just noticed there is no closing double quote(") in absolutePath, path values.

Comment: Hi Rao, This is not the problem, "absolute path" actually ends with the ending quote (").

I want a way to clear all this "file" response. As you can see i am just adding the "results" object in JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Struts action is always returning a result code that is used by the action invocation to execute a result configured to this action. I suspect that result is of type `json`.

If the action returning `json` result then by default the `root` property is initialized to the action instance or a model if you are using model-driven action.

It means that all public properties of the `root` object will be serialized to JSON. You can control this process with annotations placed on the properties, or configure the result with parameters to *include/exclude* some properties from the result.

Actually you only need to configure the `root` parameter of the result to return an object that you serialize to JSON. But because you are writing to response directly you can change the result code returned by the action to `NONE`. This is used by the actions that don't return any result.

Comment: Hi Roman, How i can change the result code returned by the action to NONE? Is there any struts2 property which i need to change in struts.xml or some where else? any sample piece of code?

Comment: Alirght got it working as per your advise. Just changed the return type from "success" to "none" in struts2 action
Return Action.NONE

Worked smoothly and it is not just returning the JSON which i want and not adding any thing extra.